A free group $F$ of rank $n$ has a subset $Y$ of cardinality $n$ which generates $F$. Is $F$ free on $Y$?
Let $F$ be a free group of rank $n$. Suppose $Y$ is a subset of $F$ with cardinality $n$ such that $F=\left< Y \right>$. Must $F$ be free on $Y$?
(Here freeness on a subset $X$ is defined as, for each group $G$ and function $\alpha: X\to G$, $\alpha$ can be extended to a unique homomorphism $F\to G$.)
Of course the $n$ in question is assumed to be finite, because it is the only nontrivial case. Indeed, were it infinite, let $F$ be free on an infinite subset $X$, choose any element $x$ of $X$, and now $\lvert X \cup \{x^2\}\rvert = |X|$ but $F$ is not free on $X\cup \{x^2\}$, a counterexample.
Now what can be said about the finite case? Any help is appreciated, and it would be best if your answer uses only the elementary facts and theorems on free groups.
Edit (Adding my attempts in case it get closed): tried to find a counterexample and failed; proved the statement "If $F$ is free on $X$ and $Y$ generates $F$, then $|X|\leq |Y|$, where $\left|-\right|$ denotes cardinality of a set", and did not find it of much use.

Why the downvotes? I don't think it is trivial

Yes, it must freely generate. This Math.SE Q&A gives a nicely elementary proof. Note, however, in the statement at the top of that post, the questioner forgot to specify that this $S$ must generate all of $F_n$, though that intention is clear from the title. (Their $S$ is your $Y$.)

A link to the older question is usually given as a comment, not as an answer.

Thanks for spotting that error in the body of that post. I edited that post to fix the error.

Thanks @Tzimmo, didn't know that yet.

Thanks for the reference! Btw how do you find a duplicate question, I searched math SE all over but couldn't even find a similar one

@Cyankite, I googled for terms like "site:math.stackexchange.com" "generating set" "free group" "f_n" and poked through dozen or so until I found that. It takes a bit of patience sometimes.

@Cyankite How did you search, which keywords did you use?

@DietrichBurde I didn't quite carefully choose my keywords and my search relies heavily on the "Related" column.... This sometimes becomes useful but depends on luck

@Tzimmo You are right, but you may not remember that a New Contributor with reputation 1 can't post a comment :)
